# Remote JMX invocation failed with ClassNotFoundException: ... (no security manager: RMI class loader disabled

Tags: java, jboss, rmi, jmx

I try to invoke the method of MBean from web application from Tomcat. Target MBean is running under JBoss 4.2.3. Both Tomcat and JBoss applications use the same version of jar with the same class, but on invoking I see the following exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: ...thisClass... (no security manager: RMI class loader disabled)
    at sun.rmi.server.LoaderHandler.loadClass(LoaderHandler.java:375)
    at sun.rmi.server.LoaderHandler.loadClass(LoaderHandler.java:165)
    at java.rmi.server.RMIClassLoader$2.loadClass(RMIClassLoader.java:620)
    at org.jboss.system.JBossRMIClassLoader.loadClass(JBossRMIClassLoader.java:91)
    at java.rmi.server.RMIClassLoader.loadClass(RMIClassLoader.java:247)
    at sun.rmi.server.MarshalInputStream.resolveClass(MarshalInputStream.java:197)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1575)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1496)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1732)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1329)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:351)
    at java.util.ArrayList.readObject(ArrayList.java:593)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor164.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:974)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1849)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1753)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1329)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:351)
    at java.util.HashMap.readObject(HashMap.java:1030)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor163.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:974)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1849)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1753)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1329)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readArray(ObjectInputStream.java:1667)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1323)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:351)
    at java.rmi.MarshalledObject.get(MarshalledObject.java:142)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl$6.run(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1513)
    ... 20 more
```

I think that JBoss doesn't use own class but try to download this class from somewhere and fails with "no security manager: RMI class loader disabled". But how to change this behavior  to use local already loaded class. Or maybe I mistake in this guess..?

Answer (score 1):

Dynamic class loading with the -Djava.rmi.server.codebase property is rarely actually needed, it's much simpler to just compile the interfaces plus any serialized class implementations into both the client and server.

Read this answer for more details:
[RMI Question - Where do clients get a definition for remote classes that have not been added to registry?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4762430/rmi-question-where-do-clients-get-a-definition-for-remote-classes-that-have-not/4822441#4822441)

Comment: Just to clarify here for anyone reading this post; when it says "compile the interfaces + classes into both client and server", make sure you don't end up using the same JAR file for both your server  and client deployments. For clients make sure you compile only the required classes in the JAR provided.

Answer (score 0):

did you provide the -Djava.rmi.server.codebase property while running the server.include this property and it should work.