# Where do clients get definitions for remote classes that have not been added to registry?

Tags: java, rmi

Ive managed to create an RMI application that does what i need it to do quite succesfully, but im having a bit of trouble getting my head around where client obtains definitions for remote objects. for example:

I have a server that registers itself with the rmiregistry (allowing clients to call methods on it).

`UnicastRemoteObject.exportObject(new Server(), 0);`

running `reg.list()` confirms that my server has indeed been added to the registry. I have another remote object (rObj) running on the same JVM as the server. This is not added to the registry.

In my client, i can get the definition of my Server class by looking up `Server` in the rmiregistry:

`reg.lookup("Server")`

after this can freely create instances of rObj. The crux of my question is, where does my client get a definition for rObj even though its never been added to registry.

I know it must come from the server as thats where the class and interface are stored. Does the connection to `Server` automatically open the pipe for other remote classes to received?

If so, how does the client know to look on the server for the remote class. Is the server treated almost as an extension to the clients classpath (it will resort to checking the server for classes that arent in its own classpath)?

Comment: Is rObj used inside Server instance? Is it returned from any method of Server?

Comment: Its a parameter for a server method but its not returned by any server method

Comment: maybe I am wrong here, but, if the rObj is a parameter of a remote method then the local client should have a class definition of the rObj you want to pass. therefore exposing via RMI the Server object also exposes the rObj class that you might need as a parameter.

Comment: The wording on this question is confusing. I think that if you added code snippets from your server and your client it would be easier to understand the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, realize that it's not necessary to set up dynamic classloading from the server in order to use RMI. If you compile the interface and implementation into both the client and server jars, then everything will work fine. That is how I've almost always implemented RMI.

If you have a good reason for loading the classes dynamically from the server, you'll need to set up an HTTP server somewhere that has the interfaces and implementation classes (preferably in a jar file, although a class directory will work too). This doesn't happen automatically as part of RMI, you need to build the jars and put them somewhere on your web server. Then launch the client with a system property indicating the URL to this jar file:

```
-Djava.rmi.server.codebase=http://webline/public/mystuff.jar
```

This is explained in full detail here: http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/rmi/codebase.html

Answer (score 1):

If you use `new` to create new instances of the same type (say, `T`) as `rObj`, then of course the Java compiler knew the definition of `T`, and your application also knows it at runtime. In this case, no RMI is involved at all.

But maybe I misunderstood your question? How exactly do you "freely create instances of rObj"?

**Update:** I'm eating my words here, of course being able to compile the file, and having the class available on the classpath at runtime or two different issues. Since you were not mentioning the classpath at all, I was assuming you'd somehow ended up having the classes on the client-side anyway.

Comment: meaning i can create new instances of `rObj` on the client. Do the client and server need to be compiled together?

Comment: @richzilla : How do you do it? With "new" or any other API?

Comment: using new. So i just have `new rObj()`

Comment: So `rObj` is actually the type of the name? This is very confusing, as per the naming convention class names should be uppercase, and you also called `rObj` "another remote object".
But in any case, my point was that you already needed the type `rObj` at compiletime, so absolutely no RMI is involved in creating an instance.